# How to create a list<IPAddress> from string

Tags: c#, list, ip-address

I have a string of IP addresses `string ip = "123.37.71.238,123.37.71.239"` (It is a example, actually it has around 100 addresses)
Need to generate list of this string

How can I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have multiple IP Address in your string separated by comma `,` then you can do:

```
string ip = "123.37.71.238,123.37.71.239";
List<IPAddress> ipAddressList = ip.Split(',')
                                  .Select(IPAddress.Parse)
                                  .ToList();
```

If you want to use `IPAddress.TryParse` then you can do:

```
IPAddress tempIP = null;
List<IPAddress> safeList = ip.Split(',')
                             .Where(r => IPAddress.TryParse(r, out tempIP))
                             .Select(r => tempIP)
                             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
var list = ip.Split(',').Select(n => IPAddress.Parse(n)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution...

```
ip.Split(",");
```

Then you'll have an array of IP address strings, which you can then call ToList() on.